# Bitcore install doesn't work

Tags: bitcore

I have tried to install Bitcore on Ubuntu.
I have already installed node and npm.

```
bitcoin@node-1:/$ npm -v
6.14.4
bitcoin@node-1:/$ node -v
v12.16.3
```

But when I try to install bitcor using this command:

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm=true bitcore
```

I got this error message:

```
zmq.target.mk:111: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/zmq/binding.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/zmq/binding.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/usr/lib/node_modules/bitcore/node_modules/zmq/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-99-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/lib/node_modules/bitcore/node_modules/zmq
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: bufferutil@1.2.1 (node_modules/bitcore/node_modules/bufferutil):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: utf-8-validate@1.2.2 (node_modules/bitcore/node_modules/utf-8-validate):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: utf-8-validate@1.2.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! zmq@2.15.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the zmq@2.15.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/bitcoin/.npm/_logs/2020-04-30T18_22_00_011Z-debug.log
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41974382/8253658

Comment: I tried, but not fixed